# How to create a bidirectional hash map in Redis?

Tags: redis, hashmap

I have a collection where each Foo maps to exactly one Bar, and each Bar maps to exactly one Foo. I need to be able to look up the corresponding Foo given a Bar, and look up the corresponding Bar given a Foo.

In order to do this, at the moment, I have created two hashmaps, and each time I do an insert, I perform 2 `HSET`s, one on each hashmap:

```
HSET fooToBar foo1 bar1
HSET barToFoo bar1 foo1
```

After this, lookups are very easy in either direction:

```
//Look up bar given a foo
HGET fooToBar foo1
//Look up foo given a bar
HGET barToFoo bar1
```

However, I am not completely satisfied with this solution. In the application I am using this in, space constraints are going to be more important than speed constraints, and this I would prefer to have just one data structure instead of two, even if it means a more expensive look up (within reason).

Is there a better way to implement a bidirectional hash map in Redis?

Comment: How big are your objects?

Comment: @AnthonyPalmer Each one is not very large, but there are a lot of them (millions). Foos are strings about 40-150 characters long. Bars are actually integers, 6-8 digits, but were converted between integers and strings in order to be used in Redis hash maps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can store your data in a sorted set instead of a hash, the foos are strings so those will be your values, and bars are integers so those will be your scores.

Adding a new foo.

```
ZADD myzset bar foo
```

Getting bar using foo.

```
ZSCORE myzset foo
```

Getting foo using bar

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE myzset bar bar
```

Keep in mind hgets are O(1). zscore is O(1) as well but zrangebyscore is O(log(N)+M) where N is the member count in the sorted set and M is the number of elements returned. Not sure if this will save you space but worth a shot I think.